# Polymorphism association in Sybase PowerDesigner

Tags: polymorphism, sybase, powerdesigner

I want to make polymorphism between 4 Entities in Sybase PowerDesigner tool, but there is no explanation how to do this in conceptual data model.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that term "polymorphism" is applicable to Object Oriented Model but not to Conceptual Data Model.

If you want to describe 4 entities with the same behavior you should generate OOM model from CDM model or use inheritance in CDM.
But "inheritance" is not the same as "polymorphism".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that CDM is the best practice for "logical/conceptual" analysis.
Some years ago I started using OOM Analysis Model instead of CDM.
You are be able to use UML notation with OOM Analysis Model but this model is not associated with a concrete language. This kind of model provides the same functionality as CDM, but you use UML-notation. As a result, there are no problems with such OOP terms as inheritance and polymorphism. You are also able also to generate PDM or OOM(Java/C#/...) from OOM Analysis.